# Вывести число, если введено число иначе 0 на python

Tags: python, математика, олимпиада

Требуется вывести конкретное число, если оно было введено, иначе вывести 0 если было введено какое-либо другое число. На вход подаются исключительно натуральные числа. Нельзя пользоваться условными операторами, функциями и т.д. Только алгебраические операторы.
Пример задания: Вывести число 3 если было введено число 3, иначе вывести 0.
Я так и не смог придумать решение.

Comment: @Harry А что удалили ответ? Ключевой момент же вы нашли, подправьте, да и всё.

Comment: Это не я их удаляю, я так и не успел увидеть ответ. Мне ответили первый раз и ветка ответов удалилась, затем второй, тоже её удалили...

Comment: Я понимаю, что не вы, автор ответа удалил.

Comment: @MBo Да просто неудобно — так ошибся...

Comment: @Harry Со всеми бывает. Зря не исправили, находка про два частных классная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, если кому-то понадобится, я нашел ответ: 3 * ((a // 3) * (3 // a)).
Вместо 'а' подставляете свое число которое проверяете, вместо числа 3 подставляете искомое число, к которому ищите соответствие.